# C++ Expat and XML parsing

Tags: c++, xml, expat-parser

I am new to using expat. I am trying to figure out how XML_SetUserData is intended to do. In my case, I have a list of class A objects and I need to populate this list as I parse the XML stream.

So far, I was planning on using a singleton to represent this single list. 
Is the XML_SetUserData to eliminate the need for my list being a singleton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. Just pass `XML_SetUserData` a pointer to whatever struct or class holds the necessary state, and cast it back from (void*) inside your handler.

A useful trick is to define a base class with static callback member functions that forward calls from expat to virtual member functions. In this scenario, `XML_SetUserData` provides a convenient mechanism to pass the `this` pointer through to the static callbacks.

Comment: any advantage other than eliminating a global? I still need to keep track of what "element" is being parsed in my data structure, global or not, both. Correct?

Comment: @reza: Yes, you have to do all your own tracking. I've added a common usage scenario that highlights one additional benefit (though avoiding globals is the primary motivator for passing user data through an API in this manner).